# feign-okhttp post request with url query parameters

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, okhttp, spring-cloud-feign

I currently have replaced httpurlconnection to feign-okhttp in my projects. I use the following edition:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>9.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

but I got a problem when I post this url: "http://gclife-platform-service:20000/v1/user/login/log?userId=ea9dd2f707a54b11b03193c35b2ad3a4&error=SUCCESS"
The log from server side as following:

```
Received [1.1
cache-control: no-cache
...
```

But "Received [1.1" should be:

```
Received [POST v1/user/login/log?userId=ea9dd2f707a54b11b03193c35b2ad3a4&error=SUCCESS HTTP/1.1
```

So this caused the parse problem.

```
2018-05-05 10:10:04.076 DEBUG 6525 --- [io-20000-exec-9] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor : Error parsing HTTP request header
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
```

when I post url with no query parameters like "http://gclife-platform-service:20000/v1/message/sms/verifycode/check", I got:

```
Received [POST /v1/message/sms/verifycode/check HTTP/1.1
```

This is the correct result.
How can I get the correct log like this?  Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This exception can occur when you try to execute https request from client on endpoint which isn't https enabled. Client will encrypt request data when server is expecting raw data.

**Change https:// to http:// in your client url.**

Comment: Thanks. But post  "http://gclife-platform-service:20000/v1/message/sms/verifycode/check" is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake.
print Feign header and find Content-Length was duplicate definition.
[image]